# Why should I not insert serialized arrays into my database field?

Tags: php, mysql, session, serialization

I just saw the first comment to this question [Inserting into a serialized array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588957/inserting-into-a-serialized-array-in-php) and it made me wonder why? Especially seeing that when you use database managed sessions (database based session handling) that is exactly what happens, the session handler inserts a serialized array into a database field.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4894041/php-is-it-bad-design-to-serialize-objects-and-stick-them-in-the-database-for-lat/4894100

Comment: @alexantd I would tend to agree except that the question you've highlighted doesn't explain why it is not a good idea IF PHP itself would use it. Thanks though you are right I should have checked better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with this in certain contexts. Session management is definitely one of those instances where this would be deemed acceptable. The thing to remember is that if you ever find yourself trying to relate data between the serialized data and any fields in your database you've made a huge design flaw and unfortunately this is something that I have seen people try to do.

Take any "never do x" with a grain of salt as almost any technique can be the correct one in certain circumstances. The advice is usually directed towards noobies who are very apt to misunderstand proper usage and code themselves into a very nasty corner.

Comment: As mentioned in Jon Skeet's answer above, I can see that for corresponding data you wouldn't want it serialized. I just didn't understand why it would be allowed for session data, but since session data is really only for PHP it would be safe. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Why would you accept an answer to a subjective question <1 hour after asking it? It seems like you already had your mind made up and were just looking for some confirmation. Many will disagree with the green checkmark for reasons that they no longer have any incentive to explain. I would only emphasize very strongly the "in certain contexts" portions of Mr. Ruport's answer. Triple emphasis on "certain".

Comment: @alexantd - Yes, your answer on the duplicate question you linked is more exhaustive.  Enjoy a hero cookie.

Answer (score 3):

How certain are you that you'll never want to get at that data from any platform other than PHP?

I don't know about PHP's form of serialization, but the default binary serialization format from every platform I *do* know about is inoperable with other platforms... typically it's not a good idea to data encoded for just a single frontend into a database.

Even if you don't end up using any other languages, it means the database itself isn't going to know anything about the information - so you won't be able to query on it etc. Maybe that's not a problem in your case - but it's definitely something to bear in mind.

Comment: Agreed, if I were working with normal data it makes sense not to serialize. I just had never heard of this before and as I mentioned I knew that PHP does in fact use serialization it made me wonder.

Answer (score 2):

The main argument against serialized data is that serialized data are hard to search through and impossible to do so efficiently i.e., without retrieving the records in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the data. By storing a language-specific data structure in a field you're tied to that language and you're also giving up anything the DB can give you. You won't have indexes on specific fields, can't run simple updates, can't extract partial data, can't have data check, referential integrity and so on.

Comment: What kind of stuff would you store in that serialized session that would be useful?