# How can i store object in MySql Database?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

can i store some object in MySql Database? Because I am making a online or offline support system by MySql. So it is important to store all data as Object. Do you have better Idea except Object?

This is Damo example about object

```
$data = array(
                'user_id' => 1, //$userId,
                'payment_id' => $payment_id,
                'hash' => $hash,
                'conversation' => $object,
                'amount' => $paypal->getTransactions()[0]->getAmount()->getTotal(),
                'description' => $paypal->getTransactions()[0]->getDescription()
            );
$this->db->insert($this->table, $data);
```

Comment: what you want exactly. How many columns are in your table?

Comment: You would have to have each key in the database and then insert based on that. A query like `"INSERT INTO something (someKey1,someKey2) VALUES ('{$somevalue->someKey1}', '{$somevalue->someKey2}');"` The object would have properties that match the key.

Comment: anyway you can serialize those object before insert

Comment: @AlexSlipknot You could serialize it - but I wouldn't; it breaks normalisation rules and ties the data to the application; serialized PHP data would be useless to anything else reading the database. In short - it's generally a terrible idea.

Comment: @CD001 well, if object is simple you can. If not - you can implement own serialization with __sleep

Comment: @AlexSlipknot - you *can* but you still shouldn't; say, with the example given, you wanted to retrieve all transactions for a given user. How would you do it if is't just a load of serialized objects in a column? How would you update the `complete` property of that object?

Comment: Ah, in this case completely agree

Comment: Now it is possible in many way by using MySql update feature. I have write 3 soluation as my answer. Please read and give me some feed back. I prefer to use soluation 1.

Comment: I wouldn't store this in one column. I would make a table with user_id, payment_id, hash etc. columns. It would make updating a single field easier. You can always select a row and convert it to an object if you need to. Especially if you are using some sort of ORM, this would be automatic anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySql has added many features in MySql 5.7. Now you can do it in many ways.

> Oracle, like Big Data is now Integrating in MySQL.
>
> MySql has Unlocked New Big Data Insights with MySQL & Hadoop.

**Solution 1:** You can use MySQL as a Document Store. It is possible to store many many object as JSON. It is highly recommended and Extendable.

> MySQL Document Store = (MySql + NoSql).
>
> X Dev API will help to produce JSON with SQL and CRUD operation over X
>   Protocol. Also there is the possibility of maintaining X Session.

It will be best for transparent data sending and sharing for chat application or group Application.

**Solution 2:** `MySql Sysbench: Read Only` is another great solution. It will be very very fast and scalable to make group chat Applications.

**Solution 3:** Use `MySql 5.7 : InnoDB, NoSql with Memcached API` which will interact directly with storage engine InnoDB. It is 6X faster than MySql 5.6.

> Currently, FaceBook is using this technology. Because it is very fast.

For more details:

https://www.mysql.com/news-and-events/web-seminars/introducing-mysql-document-store/

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/document-store-setting-up.html

https://www.oracle.com/big-data/index.html

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Dk517M-_7o

Comment: Soluation 1 will be best. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/document-store.html

Comment: I just found the post because I was looking stuff about JSON storage in MySQL. One of the advantages is that you can index the data contained in JSON using virtual columns. This is way better than serialization. Serialization should not be used for converting data to storable format.

Answer (score 5):

You have to transform your object in a string to save your full object.
For that, use **serialize** in PHP:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.serialization.php

Then you will be able to **unserialize** and get back your object.

Comment: Generally speaking, this is a *bad* idea.

Comment: Can you explain why?

Comment: Say you want to get the object from your database which has a property "x" - you have to extract all the data and unseralize the objects to determine which one has that property; your data is no longer normalized at all. You should have indexed columns that map the object properties then you can retrieve specific data, or update specific properties with ease in future. Also, should you ever port the application to Ruby or whatever, Serialized PHP data is potentially useless.

Comment: In some contexts, serialize can be useful, when it's datas you will never sort, just a group of datas. But if you need to select specifics entries, indeed you shouldn't use that !

Comment: As I said, *generally* ;) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5555506/why-should-i-not-insert-serialized-arrays-into-my-database-field

Comment: Because I am making a online or offline support system by MySql. So it is important to store all data as Object. Do you have better Idea except Object?

Comment: You can create a specific table with all the fields you need, and send the object attributes to the right column.

Comment: Thanks How can i store conversation? There can be many many line data!!

Comment: Create a table "conversation", one entry = one message. Create your columns like "username, id, message, ip, ...".

Comment: @ShaponPal - with a one-to-many relationship; 1 table could be the "support ticket" and another could be the conversation events relating to that ticket. The conversation table would hold the id of the ticket in a column; doesn't really matter if there are 100 records or a million as long as the `ticket_id` is properly indexed.

Comment: @ShaponPal probably a relational database as long as it's properly indexed - but it would depend on what you're doing with caching. Either way, unless you're expecting many thousands of requests a minute it's going to make no appreciable difference.

Comment: This is bad if you need to query the data contained in serialied string. You have to use JSON, the advantage is that you can index the data contained in JSON using virtual columns. This is way better than serialization. Serialization should not be used for converting data to storable format.